# Why does Postgresql function not work as expected

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-function

I have table like this

```
 id|    booking_id       |       status         |         message             |          created_at
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1 | 1467                | VALIDATE             | Validate Payment            | 2022-03-18 07:43:20.688+00
 2 | 1901                | SUCCESS              |                             | 2022-03-18 07:51:58.072+00
 3 | 1847                | FAILED               | payment is insufficient     | 2022-03-18 08:16:05.79+00
```

I create get function like this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_booking_status(booking_id BIGINT)
  RETURNS JSONB
  LANGUAGE SQL
  SECURITY DEFINER
AS $$
SELECT to_jsonb(result)
FROM (SELECT * FROM booking.booking_status WHERE booking.booking_status.booking_id = booking_id) AS result
$$;
```

I tried to call function like this

```
SELECT get_booking_status(1467)
```

but return json all 3 row instead of 1 row with `booking_id` 1467

can you explain root cause ?

Comment: Rename the parameter to a name different than the column

Comment: Note that you can simplify the query using `select to_jsonb(bs) from booking_booking_status bs where ...`

Comment: FYI, the first booking in  `booking.booking_status.booking_id` is redundant as Postgres does not have cross database references in queries, so you are always referring to the current database. Also the query will fail if run in another database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause of you problem is naming your parameter (`booking_id`) the same as a column name (`booking_id`) in your table. When processing a query any unqualified reference follows a hierarchy to determine the correct reference; the first being the table column. In this case `where booking.booking_status.booking_id = booking_id` both references to *booking_id* are interpreted as referring to the table column. Which is true for every row in the table. You have basically 2 choices: change the parameter name or qualify with the function name.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_booking_status(booking_id BIGINT)
  RETURNS JSONB
  LANGUAGE SQL
  SECURITY DEFINER
AS $$
SELECT to_jsonb(result)
  FROM (SELECT * 
          FROM booking.booking_status 
         WHERE booking.booking_status.booking_id 
             = get_booking_status.booking_id) AS result
$$;
```

Also see comments from @a_horse_with_no_name and @AdrianKlaver above.